# will an in clause always return the same order in mysql

Tags: mysql

ok so i have this query

```
select price from product where product_id in (49, 50, 51)
```

and I want to know if the three records returned will be in the same order as my in clause. SO for example

```
100.0000
166.0000
55.0000
```

will 100.0000 belong to 49, 166.0000 to 50 and 55.0000 to 51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the same order you have specified within in clause you have to use field() function.

```
select price from product where product_id in (49, 50, 51)
order by field(product_id,49,50,51)
```

Answer (score 3):

No. They will be returned in the order which they are encountered when selecting from the product table. Ordering in a database is an expensive operation, so it won't sort anything unless you explicitly tell it to. You should have an `order by` clause if order is important.

Answer (score 2):

No

An IN clause does not sort your rows.
Also IN clauses suck, if you can avoid them do.

```
SELECT price from product where product_id BETWEEN 49 AND 51
```

is a better query. If you want your query in a particular order do `order by somefield` at the end.

**More on IN**
In your use case you don't need IN, because you can trade 3 comparisons with 2, which is faster.
If your query is:

```
select price from product where product_id in (51547, 417853, 879823)
```

Then using `IN` is fine. **This is the only case where `IN` doesn't suck**

Especially never use `IN` with a subselect

[image]**coding horror**

```
SELECT price FROM product WHERE product_id IN 
    (SELECT product_id FROM tableX)
```

Replace this with

```
SELECT price FROM product 
INNER JOIN tableX ON (product.product_id = tableX.product_id)
```

Which is much faster.